# Object reference error when executing robocopy using powershell invoke-command

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I try to execute the robocopy command using powershell invoke-command on remote machine.

Here is the simple script I try to execute

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myremotemachine -Credential xxx\abcd -ScriptBlock  {
    $deploymentDrive = "D"
    Robocopy "${deploymentDrive}:\myservice\" "${deploymentDrive}:\backup\myservicebackup\" /MIR /XA:SH /R:5 /W:15 /MT:32 /LOG:"${deploymentDrive}:\backup\copyofmyservicebackup.log"
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: wrong syntax in your strings. Use "$($deploymentDrive):\myservice" and "$($deploymentDirve):\backup\myservicebackup\"

Comment: Works for me. Can you provide more information (like the actual error message, including details).

Comment: Here is the exact error

Program 'Robocopy.exe' failed to run: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.At line:14 char:5
+     Robocopy "${deploymentDrive}:\myservice\" "${deploymentDrive} ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
    + PSComputerName        : myremotemachine

Comment: @DavidBrabant Also the same syntax with copy-item command is working fine, 

    $DatePart = Get-Date -Format M-d-yy-h-m-tt
    $backupfolder = "OANext-" + $DatePart
    Robocopy "d:\myservice\" "d:\backup\$backupFolder\myservice\" /MIR /XA:SH /XJD /R:5 /W:15 /MT:32
    #Copy-Item "d:\myservice\" "d:\backup\$backupFolder\myservice\" -Force -Recurse